# Laravel POST api request going as null. how to make post request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have made a get request to the route called /fetch, where i am getting some information from the api and automatically save it to database, also i have another piece of api, which needed to POST this piece of information and also store it to database with first piece of code, so, how can i do this?

i created another rouute called Route::post and then in the controller make post function also and bring this code below, when i Die and Dump this i get NULL, but when i die and dump $post without ->json() or decode or something, i get some codes, but i cannot find some info from api in it (?) how can i do this? and also do i need another route for this? or can i use previuos route which i used for get request ?

`$post = Http::post('some api')->json();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
$uri = "https://example.com/api/your-api-url-here";
$params['headers'] = [
     'Content-type' => 'application/json'
];
$params['body'] = [
     'username' => 'helloWorld'
];
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, $params);
$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
dd($data);
```

And don't forget to use Guzzle/Http in your project, you simply can install guzzle http and use it in your controller like

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it  didnt work, i used this --->  $url = 'api';
   $client = new Client();
   $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'form_params' => [
     'code' => $country['code'],
    ],
   ]);
   $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
   dd($data);    but it still doesnt work, it send only for one country, but need it to loop and send like 100 times for each country i have

Comment: Result is for only 1 country code, but i need to see result for ALL country codes i have